# MySQL update changes affect rest of the data

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql update here and when the user make changes to one selection category it would duplicate that selection to the rest of the other selection too. Below is a sample scenario where only the 1st CD category was change and it's reflecting the same for the rest. How do I get "nmc_category.catDesc ='$pCDCategory" to only update that entry only ?

Sample:
[image]

```
$sql = "UPDATE nmc_cd "
     . "JOIN nmc_category ON (nmc_cd.catID = nmc_category.catID) "
     . "JOIN nmc_publisher ON (nmc_cd.pubID = nmc_publisher.pubID) "
     . "SET nmc_cd.CDTitle='$pCDTitle',nmc_cd.CDYear='$pCDYear',nmc_cd.CDPrice='$pCDPrice',nmc_category.catDesc ='$pCDCategory', nmc_publisher.pubName = '$pCDPubName' , nmc_cd.pubID ='$pCDPubID', nmc_publisher.pubID='$pCDPubID' "
     . "WHERE nmc_cd.CDID='$pCDID'";
```

nmc_cd table:

[image]

nmc_category table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this command
      SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

Comment: Should this be place before UPDATE line ?

Comment: It shows syntax error when i place it like this -> $sql = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0 "
     . "UPDATE nmc_cd "

Comment: you are using mysql then no need to assign any variable directly execute this command....in MySql command prompt.

Comment: So it's like sql = "SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES " . "UPDATE nmc_cd "

Comment: Not like that.. Directly place it SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; in my sql command prompt.